# Download the Tour of Heroes app and tutorial webpages having robots.txt

Tags: linux, wget

I like to download the Tour of Heroes app and tutorial webpages (https://v13.angular.io/tutorial) for offline viewing.
I tried wget on Linux Mint 20.3 Cinnamon.
I suspect that the robots.txt file causes the Retrying issue.
Please help.
Thanks.

```
$ wget --limit-rate=200k --no-clobber --convert-links --random-wait -r -p -E -e robots=off -U mozilla https://v13.angular.io/tutorial
Both --no-clobber and --convert-links were specified, only --convert-links will be used.
--2022-07-17 08:09:50--  https://v13.angular.io/tutorial
Resolving v13.angular.io (v13.angular.io)... 151.101.65.195, 151.101.1.195
Connecting to v13.angular.io (v13.angular.io)|151.101.65.195|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘v13.angular.io/tutorial.html’

2022-07-17 08:09:50 (1.51 MB/s) - ‘v13.angular.io/tutorial.html’ saved [16907]

--2022-07-17 08:09:50--  https://v13.angular.io/assets/opensearch.xml
Length: 545 [application/xml]
Saving to: ‘v13.angular.io/assets/opensearch.xml’
v13.angular.io/assets/opensearch.xml    100%[===============================================================================>]     545  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2022-07-17 08:09:50 (18.2 MB/s) - ‘v13.angular.io/assets/opensearch.xml’ saved [545/545]



... snipped for brevity



$ Retrying.
Retrying.: command not found
$ 
$ Resolving www.adjust.com (www.adjust.com)... 178.162.216.219
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
$ Connecting to www.adjust.com (www.adjust.com)|178.162.216.219|:443... connected.
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
$ HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
HTTP: command not found
$ Length: 186 [text/plain]
Length:: command not found
$ Saving to: ‘www.adjust.com/robots.txt’
Saving: command not found
$ 
$ www.adjust.com/robots.txt               100%[===============================================================================>]     186  --.-KB/s    in 0s      
www.adjust.com/robots.txt: line 1: Sitemap:: command not found
www.adjust.com/robots.txt: line 2: User-agent:: command not found
www.adjust.com/robots.txt: line 3: Disallow:: command not found
www.adjust.com/robots.txt: line 4: Disallow:: command not found
www.adjust.com/robots.txt: line 5: Disallow:: command not found
www.adjust.com/robots.txt: line 6: Disallow:: command not found
$ 
$ 2022-07-17 08:33:01 (9.95 MB/s) - ‘www.adjust.com/robots.txt’ saved [186/186]


$ wget --version
GNU Wget 1.20.3 built on linux-gnu.
```

Comment: Try adding `--reject robots.txt`, if robots.txt is causing wget problems.

Comment: Adding --reject robots.txt fixes the Retrying issue :).
Downloaded: 17 files, 773K in 2.9s (268 KB/s)
Open the file:///tutorialb/v13.angular.io/tutorial.html get a blank page.

Answer (score 1):

This particular `robots.txt` file caused `wget` problems, as it wasn't able
to parse it for links. This is probably just a bug in `wget`.

The problem was solved by adding to `wget` the parameter of
`--reject robots.txt`, for it to ignore the file.

However, not every downloaded page will function the same as it does
in its original context, so success is only guaranteed for the
simpler webpages.

Comment: I also tried curl but the downloaded page do not function the same as it does in its original context.